# how to show an arrow to the only li item that has sub-menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create styling for nested menu, which is pretty much done but just a simple step is left that i am trying to figure out how to fix.

I want to show Arrows to the `li` items that has `sub-menu`.
It seems pretty easy to do, but with the styling of nested menus, its getting more complex.

Currently the problem is, when hovering to a list item that has no sub-menu inside it, it shows the arrow. Which it should not show.

Here's the Codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obgWvr

This is my html code, generated from Wordpress nav menu:

```
<div style="height:105px; background:url(http://s2.postimg.org/tlyo9809h/bg_header_strip.png); border-bottom:7px solid #00a94e; position:relative;"> 
<div class="mainContainer menu-header-bottom-items" style="height:105px; position:relative;">

      <div class="menu-main-menu-container"><ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-286" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-286"><a href="http://localhost/wp/sealant-solutions/">Solutions</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-285" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-has-children menu-item-285"><a href="http://localhost/wp/products/">Products</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-312" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-has-children menu-item-312"><a href="http://localhost/wp/cups/">Cups</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-313" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-313"><a href="http://localhost/wp/pink-cup/">Pink Cup</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-314" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-has-children menu-item-314"><a href="http://localhost/wp/black-cup/">Black Cup</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-318" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-318"><a href="http://localhost/wp/test-page/">Test Page</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-315" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-has-children menu-item-315"><a href="http://localhost/wp/normal-plates/">Normal Plates</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-316" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-316"><a href="http://localhost/wp/resources/">Resources</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-317" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-317"><a href="http://localhost/wp/support/">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-291" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-291"><a href="http://localhost/wp/about/">About</a></li>
</ul></div>      



<b1r clear="all">
</div>
```

And this is the css:

```
.menu-header-bottom-items ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:105px;
    z-index:9999;
}
.menu-header-bottom-items li{
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
}

.menu-header-bottom-items li a{ 
    color:#fff;
    padding:47px 43px;
    display: block;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:300;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.menu-header-bottom-items li a:hover{ background:#00a94e;}
.menu-header-bottom-items li.current-menu-item{ background:#00a94e; margin-top:-20px; padding-bottom:20px;}

.menu-item-has-children{ position:relative;}
.menu-item-has-children ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    flex:0;
}
.menu-item-has-children:hover > ul{display:block;}
.menu-item-has-children li a{ padding:15px; text-align:left; }
.menu-item-has-children li { padding:0; float:none; background:url(http://s2.postimg.org/tlyo9809h/bg_header_strip.png);}
.menu-item-has-children ul ul { left:100%;top:0;}
ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children{ background:url(http://s28.postimg.org/ilizrjzax/arrow_right.png) no-repeat 95% center,url(http://s2.postimg.org/tlyo9809h/bg_header_strip.png);}
ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:hover{ background:#00a94e url(http://s28.postimg.org/ilizrjzax/arrow_right.png) no-repeat 95% center;}
li.current-menu-item > ul{ margin-top:20px;}
.sub-menu li a:hover{ background:#00a94e;}
ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children a:hover{ background:#00a94e url(http://s28.postimg.org/ilizrjzax/arrow_right.png) no-repeat 95% center;}
.menu-header-bottom-items li:hover{ background:#00a94e;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the same styling you have on the submenu items that have children to the parent level menu (that have children)

```
li.menu-item-has-children,
li.menu-item-has-children:hover{
      background:url(http://s28.postimg.org/ilizrjzax/arrow_right.png) no-repeat 95% center;
}
```

I removed the following because it was overriding the background arrow image (and is applied to the li anyway)

```
.menu-header-bottom-items li a:hover{
  background:#00a94e;
}
```

I also added the `>` selector to the following line because it was adding the arrow image to all of the anchors of elements that had submenus (i.e. third level menu items that didn't have a submenu)

```
ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children > a:hover{
  background:#00a94e url(http://s28.postimg.org/ilizrjzax/arrow_right.png) no-repeat 95% center;
}
```

http://codepen.io/brn2drv99/pen/ZQYyPO

Comment: Thank you, it worked very well. Can you explain the last change? i.e. addition of `>`. What this actually do?

Comment: Certainly: [the `>` is a direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors). Essentially, it only refers to elements that are immediately inside of an element and not to elements that are wrapped in another element. As an example, using HTML: `<div><span id="s1"><span id="s2"> </span></span></div>`, the selector `div > span` refers to `#s1` only whereas `div span` refers to both span elements.

Comment: In your code, it refers to only the anchor of a parent-level item that has children elements and not the anchors actually inside those children.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to add a class to the li which has submanu.
Write css to the class to show arrow

jQuery:

```
jQuery('ul.sub-menu').parent('li').addClass("arrowStyle");
```

css:

```
.arrowStyle{
  // css for arrow
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a need of jquery for this. If you take a look at the codepen, you will notice its already showing the Arrow Styling to the menu items that has sub-menu inside. Its just the Mouse Hover that is showing ArrowStyling to the all the menu-items.